# Port opened on RHEL but nmap cannot find it

Tags: rhel7, nmap, firewalld

I am using tomcat on RHEL7 cloud instance on default `8080` port. Opened port using `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent`, reloaded using `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`. Connecting `curl 0.0.0.0:8080` works fine but I cannot access it with machine's public IP. When mapped using nmap, it only show ssh port `open` and shows `filtered` for `8080` when used `nmap -[IP] -Pn -p 8080`. I have tried doing same with `iptables` and other options from StackExchange but nothing seems to work. Any help, how do I access tomcat with public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yo say cloud instance, I assume it runs on AWS, or Google Cloud or something on that line. Did you check the securiy rules there?
AWS for example has security rules or groups for EC2 instances. Regardless what you configure on your host, you need to allow it in theses AWS security groups. It is an extra Firewall.

Comment: It's on Azure. I'll check the rules there and get back.